# How to know if a logic formula is equivalent to a Horn clause?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Take for instance $X \lor Y$. It is commonly known that this formula is not a horn clause since it does not have a minimal model. Now, does it suffice to say $\exists Minimal \ model \equiv horn \ clause$? (note: only **equivalence!** I know that it doesn't *imply* that it is a horn clause) If not, is there another way to find out?  Do I have to rewrite a formula into the shape of a horn clause possibly?

Comment: apologies for my ignorance, but what is a minimal model?

Comment: emmm, sorry, I'm pretty new to logics, It's basically the result from say a Horn satisfiability test. The smallest possible allocation that satisfies the formula. For $X \land Y$ it would be $(1,1)$ because no other allocation would satisfy the formula. Likewise, for $X \lor Y$ there are $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ which are of the same cardinality and thus there is no "minimal model"... I forgot what this was actually called...

Comment: "only equivalence! I know that it doesn't imply that it is a horn clause" but wouldn't imply be a consequence of equivalence?

Answer (score 1):

To be honestly, I don't quite understand your question on minimal model and horn clause, but for other way to find out whether a fomula is a horn class, we can check the truth table, use the following method.

Here we use the definition from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause#Definition):

> Definition (Horn clause)
> A Horn clause is a clause (a disjunction of literals) with at most one positive, i.e. unnegated, literal.

In another words, say a formula $\phi$ with literals $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n$ is a horn clause if and only if

the valuation of $\phi$ is false for exactly one truth condition, such truth condition is either $$(p_1,\dots,p_n)=(1,\dots,1)$$
or for exactly one $i$ s.t. $p_i=0,p_{k\neq i}=1$ i.e.
$$(p_1,p_2,\dots,p_i,\dots p_n)=(1,1,\dots,0,\dots,1)$$

so we can easily tell whether a fomula is a horn clause or not from its truth table.